# How to edit my app in qtdesigner again after converting it to ui file?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt

We all know how much useful the tool Qtdesigner is. I am creating an app using  Qtdesigner and I converted my .ui file to .py file.
**Now for some reason I want to edit some designs of my app. IS there any way to do it in Qtdesigner again?**

Comment: Open the .ui with Qt Designer, modify it and then convert it back to .py

Comment: what if I chaned my .py file. I have to do that again?

Comment: I don't know it can, unless you have respected some QtDesigner standards. Look at the duplicate